# Parsing XPath using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I am writing some scripts to change some values in config (XML) files. The script will take XPath expressions and replacement values to be replaced in a source document.

If the node is found in the source document, then the value will be replaced, but if the node is not found, I need to create a new element and add required elements with attributes.

For example, in a web.config if `appSetting` exists, then change its value, if not then create a new one

```
/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='ClientValidationEnabled']/@value
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to read the XPath as an expression that lets me walk it and create a new element if needed.

Comment: Fun question! I know of no way to do this. Given that Nokogiri uses `libxml2` for all XML processing, passing the XPath on to it, I doubt that there is any parsed XPath available to Ruby. Possibly helpful to you, if you have to parse it yourself: http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-xpath-parsing/

Comment: Note that in general you won't always have a specific location available for any arbitrary XPath expression. For example, consider the expression `//foo[ancestor::bar]`; if no such element exists, and you have more than one `bar` element, where do you put it? What if no `bar` element exists, but a `foo` does?

Comment: Even better: you may be able to use the XPath PEG [here](https://github.com/jcoglan/pathology/blob/master/source/pathology/xpath.peg) along with a Ruby PEG library like [Treetop](https://github.com/nathansobo/treetop).